# How to make sum of all rows in mysql OR how to show show data in following way using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This data is showing in MySql Database

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Team
</td>
<td>
Score
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
New Zealand
</td>
<td>
10
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
2
</td>
<td>
Australia
</td>
<td>
5
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
New Zealand
</td>
<td>
5
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and I want to show data on webpage like this

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Team
</td>
<td>
Score
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
New Zealand
</td>
<td>
15
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
2
</td>
<td>
Australia
</td>
<td>
5
</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Note that in database "New Zealand" showing 2 time in Database but on webpage it showing 1 time and also its score in sum
please tell me how can I do this using mysqli

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: use `count` and `goupby ` clause

Comment: Your profile reads as *I am proffesional FrontEnd Web Developer.* - I'm sorry but I beg to differ. Plus, the word is "professional". One "f" two "s"'s. Being a professional, consists of being able to solve basic coding such as this including the ability to do research.

Answer (score 0):

Without your query I can't use your table or field names, but it would look something like this:

```
SELECT `team`, SUM(`score`) AS `score_sum` FROM `teams` GROUP BY `team`
```

This groups the rows by team and for each group, the scores are summed for that team.  You would then access the team name using `team` and the total score for each team using `score_sum` in your PHP code.  You'll have to provide more details like your query and code if this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a suggestion for your table , considering that you have already created soccer table with three columns ID,Team,Score . regardless a way you insert a data in this table , here how to get it properly

```
<?php
 include("connection.php");
 $team  = "select distinct team from soccer";
 $team2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,$team);
 $up = "0";
 $id ="1";
 echo "<table><tr><td>ID</td><td>TEAM</td><td>SCORE</td></tr><tr>";
while ($teamres = $team2->fetch_array()){
echo "<td>".$id."</td><td>".$teamres['team']."</td>";
$score = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT sum(score) FROM soccer where team ='".$teamres['team']."'");
$score2 = mysqli_fetch_row($score);
$scorere = $score2[0];
echo "<td>".$scorere."</td>";
echo "</tr>";

$id++;
$up++;
  }
echo "</table>";
?>
```